# profiling: most of my time in memmove$VARIANT$sse42

Tags: c++, profiling, cpu

According to instruments my program (written in c++x11) spend most of it time into:

```
     memmove$VARIANT$sse42
```

what does it means?

Comment: looks like you copy a lot of elements back and forth, see if you accidentally pass objects to functions by value instead of by reference

Comment: My first reflex would be to distrust a result like that. Make sure you're profiling an optimized release build and see if Visual Studio's profiler gives you the same results when using CPU sampling (which I prefer). If you have access to the VS profiler of course.

Comment: To add to Leor's comment, the function you mention is a function to copy data. A special internal version of memcpy optimized for your CPU. It will get called if you copy lots of data around, for instance if you insert data in the middle of a vector, or if you return lots of large std::vectors as function return values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking at "self time".

Don't. It's useless.
It tells you all about the leaves of your call tree, and nothing about the branches.

At the very least, you should be looking at inclusive time of a routine, as a percent of total time.
That tells you what it's responsible for - how much would be saved if the routine took no time.